# How to maintain listview scroll position after deleting items from beginning

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to delete few elements from the beginning of my listview adapter when elements number is big, for memory efficiency, I want to maintain the same visible elements, but this is not happening due to the deletion
the following is the corresponding code

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() 
        {

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
        {
            synchronized(loadLock)
            {
                if(totalItemCount>0)
                {

                    if(totalItemCount-firstVisibleItem-visibleItemCount<10 && offset!=highOffset &&load)
                    {
                        load=false;
                        offset=highOffset;
                        loadEvents();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public void loadEvents() 
{
        Response.Listener<JSONObject> response = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                JSONArray events = null;
                try 
                {
                    events = response.getJSONArray("events");
                } 
                catch (JSONException e1) 
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (events != null)
                {
                    Event event;
                    for (int i = 0; i < events.length(); i++) 
                    {
                        //filling events list
                    }
                    highOffset+=events.length();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    cleanListView();
                    load=true;
                }
            }
        };


        CustomRequest eventReq = new CustomRequest(Method.POST, URL, params,
                response, errorListener);
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(eventReq);
    }

public void cleanListView()
    {
        if(eventsList.size()>=1000)
        {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            eventsList.remove(0);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        lowOffset+=100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use RecyclerView instead of ListView, you will have automatically optimized memory performance in android.

Comment: My problem is that the adapter's arraylist might contain more than a million item so by memory efficiency i mean ArrayList objects , not views that's why RecyclerView won't help

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like [setSelectionFromTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelectionFromTop(int,%20int)), if I know how many items are getting deleted etc etc

Comment: i tried this approach before but it's not working since the scroll movement is  random ,it doesn't scroll as much as deleted